# How to compare SSDT project to entities library

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022, sql-server-data-tools

I'm using SQL Server Data Tools to develop my database, and have a library with entity classes for use by the clients and API. Is there a smart way, or automating tool, to compare my entities to the SSDT project (something like schema comparer in SSDT)?

TIA!
Dennis